# Can we define isogeny map between ordinary elliptic curve over field?

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, isogeny

Let $k$ be a field, and $E_1, E_2$ be ordinary elliptic curves over $k$.

Given isogeny map $\phi:E_1\times_k \operatorname{Spec}\overline{k}\to E_2\times_k \operatorname{Spec}\overline{k}$ over $\overline{k}$, can we define isogeny map over $k$?

In paticular,  $\operatorname{End}_{k}(E)=\operatorname{End}_{\overline{k}}(E)$?

Especially I want to know the case $k$ is finite filed.

Comment: The first claim is wrong. If $p=5$ and $E : y^2 = x^3 + x, E' : y^2 = x^3 - x$, they $E,E'$ are ordinary and isogenous over $F_{p^2}$ but not over $F_p$ (just look at their number of points, by Tate's theorem).

Comment: SAGE code: `p = 5
E = EllipticCurve(GF(p), [1, 0])
print(E.cardinality())
for a in GF(p):
    for b in GF(p):
        try:
            E1 = EllipticCurve(GF(p), [a, b])
            if E1.cardinality(extension_degree=2) == E.cardinality(extension_degree=2):
                print(E1, E1.cardinality(extension_degree=1) == E.cardinality(extension_degree=1))
        except:pass
`

Comment: A great example @Watson. You could post it as an answer! It is not difficult to find an explicit isogeny over $\Bbb{F}_{25}$. As $8\mid (25-1)$ the field has an eight root of unity $u$. Write $i=u^2$. Multiplying $y^2=x^3-x$ by $i$ gives $iy^2=ix^3-ix$, where the L.H.S. is $(uy)^2$ and the R.H.S. is $(-ix)^3+(-ix)$.